# Magento 2 How to Call JavaScript Click Function on Checkout?

Tags: magento2, onestepcheckout

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
    $( "#checkoutnext" ).click(function() { 
        alert("Test!");
    });
 });
 </script>
```

I am using this code on onepagecheckout. but not working any Idea or suggestion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
        $(document).on("click","#checkoutnext", function() {
            alert("Test!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Grate Bro. Love it. Thanks A lot for save my time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite `form.html` knockout template of `Magento_Checkout` in your theme.

**app\design\frontend\Vendorname\Themename\Magento_Checkout\web\template\billing-address\form.html**

replace below div

```
<div class="billing-address-form" data-bind="fadeVisible: isAddressFormVisible">
```

to

```
<div class="billing-address-form" data-bind="fadeVisible: isAddressFormVisible, afterRender: renderedHandler">
```

Rewrite **billing-address.js** in your theme

**app\design\frontend\Vendorname\Themename\Magento_Checkout\web\js\view\billing-address.js**

add below function in above js file

```
        /**
         * after form render handler
         *
         */
        renderedHandler: function (elements, data) {
          //add your custom js code here
        }
```